# How to fix this function? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a function that calculates the amount of gas you need by giving the distance you need to travel and your engine's consumption, however nothing happens when I click the button, here is the code:

```js
function calc() {
  var dist = document.getElementById("distance").value
  var cons = document.getElementById("cons").value
  var res = dist / 100 * cons
  res.innerText = "You need " + res + "liters of gas.";
}

function load() {
  var button = document.getElementById("button");
  button.addEventListener("click", calc, false);
}
```

```html
<main onload="load();">
  <h2>Calculate how much gas you need</h2>
  <input type="number" class="number" id="dist"><br/>
  <input type="number" class="number" id="cons"><br/><br/>
  <input type="button" class="button" id="button" value="Submit"><br/>
  <p id="res"></p>
</main>
```

Comment: There is no distance id

Comment: you cannot add onload on main element I guess. Try that calling it in bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `onload` attribute with `main` tag.

Also, you forgot to find element `#res` with `document.getElementById`.

```js
function calc() {
  const dist = document.getElementById("dist").value;
  const cons = document.getElementById("cons").value;
  const res = dist / 100 * cons;
  document.getElementById('res').innerText = "You need " + res + "liters of gas.";
}

function load() {
  const button = document.getElementById("button");
  button.addEventListener("click", calc, false);
}
```

```html
<body onload="load();">
  <main>
    <h2>Calculate how much gas you need</h2>
    <input type="number" class="number" id="dist"><br/>
    <input type="number" class="number" id="cons"><br/><br/>
    <input type="button" class="button" id="button" value="Submit"><br/>
    <p id="res"></p>
  </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues in your code:

1. You can ignore the `load()` by executing all your code in `DOMContentLoaded`.
2. You should refer the element *p* to replace the `innerText` property

I will also suggest you to be more careful in naming attributes.

**Code Example:**

```html
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    function calc() {
      var dist = document.getElementById("dist").value
      var cons = document.getElementById("cons").value
      var resEl = document.getElementById('res');
      var res = dist / 100 * cons
      resEl.innerText = "You need " +res+"liters of gas.";
    }

    var button = document.getElementById("calcButton");
    button.addEventListener("click", calc);
  }); 
</script>

<main>
    <h2>Calculate how much gas you need</h2>
    <input type="number" class="number" id="dist"><br/>
    <input type="number" class="number" id="cons"><br/><br/>
    <input type="button" class="clsButton" id="calcButton" value="Submit"><br/>
    <p id="res"></p>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you put JS code on top of the actual elements!

```
document.getElementById("distance")
```

will be undefined as the distance is being rendered below that code. moreover instead of distance I see you have `dist` in the actual element id.

Last but not list you should put your code in script tags.

```
<main onload="load();">
    <h2>Calculate how much gas you need</h2>
    <input type="number" class="number" id="dist"><br/>
    <input type="number" class="number" id="cons"><br/><br/>
    <input type="button" class="button" id="button" value="Submit"><br/>
    <p id="res"></p>
</main>


<script>
//we put script below html
function calc() {
    var dist = document.getElementById("dist").value
    var cons = document.getElementById("cons").value
    var res = dist / 100 * cons
     res.innerText = "You need " +res+"liters of gas.";
   }
function load() {
     var button = document.getElementById("button");
     button.addEventListener("click", calc, false);
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if u can do a onload on a  but u can try using onclick event on the submit button instead.

```
<input type="button" class="button" id="button" value="Submit" onclick="calc();"><br/>
```

that would do the trick aswell i believe

and in your calc() function you have to find your res div :)

```
function calc() {
  var dist = document.getElementById("distance").value
  var cons = document.getElementById("cons").value
  var res= document.getElementById("res")

  var resAnswer = dist / 100 * cons
  res.innerText = "You need " + resAnswer + "liters of gas.";
}
```